# react-native-camera iOS base64 invalid

Tags: react-native, base64, data-uri, react-native-camera

Working on a simple camera based application that needs to generate a base64 encoded data uri version of the image.  Ideally avoiding creating and storing a file on disk.  react-native-camera has options for this and successfully generates the base64 encoded string on android.

The same code in iOS results in a black screen when attempting to place it in an  tag, and the backend server similarly sees the base64 encoded image as corrupt.

```
takePicture = () => {
    if (this.state.image) {
      return this.setState({ image: undefined });
    }
    if (this.camera) {
      const quality = 1; // range of 1 to 0 with 1 being full quality.
      const base64 = true; // false skips the conversion of jpg to base64
      const doNotSave = true; // return only the base64 representation (if set to true)
      const options: TakePictureOptions = { quality, base64, doNotSave };

      this.camera
        .takePictureAsync(options)
        .then(data => {
          if (data.base64) {
            this.setState({
              image: {
                data: data.base64,
                orientation: data.pictureOrientation === 1 ? 'portrait' : 'landscape',
                height: data.height,
                width: data.width
              }
            });
            return;
          }
        })
        .catch(reason => {
          Log('takePickture().catch()', reason);
        });
    }
  };
```

taking the picture, builds the image information into state which is rendered by this jsx:

```
<Image
        source={{ uri: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${state.image.data}` }}
        resizeMethod={'resize'}
        resizeMode={'contain'}
      ></Image>
```

This all works fine for android, but a black screen is presented in iOS.  ( I recently updated to the most current version, same issue )

Comment: hi , You can try `react-native-image-crop-picker` for take picture with camera , see this link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker

Comment: Unfortunately that seems like an image picker solution, I am looking to take a picture that doesn't save to disk to avoid privacy law issues.